# Maven requires manual dependency update?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm new to Maven, using the *m2e* plugin for Eclipse. I'm still wrapping my head around Maven, but it seems like whenever I need to import a new library, like `java.util.List`, now I have to manually go through the hassle of finding the right repository for the jar and adding it to the dependencies in the POM. This seems like a major hassle, especially since some jars can't be found in public repositories, so they have to be uploaded into the local repository.

Am I missing something about Maven in Eclipse? Is there a way to automatically update the POM when Eclipse automatically imports a new library?

I'm trying to understand how using Maven saves time/effort...

Comment: You should not need to modify your pom.xml for java.util.List. What do you mean _Eclipse automatically imports a new library_? All your external libraries should be declared as dependencies in your pom.xml

Comment: If you type your source code like things: List<String> ... via ctrl-space after the Word "List" you should get a suggestion with a dropdownlist of types...if just type the code yourself List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); After that you should use Ctrl-Shift-O to complete the import list in your java file which should be filled automatically with the correct informations. Otherwise your configuration of Eclipse is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

You picked a bad example.  Portions of the actual Java Library that come with the Java Standard Runtime are there regardless of Maven configuration.

With that in mind, if you wanted to add something external, say Log4j, then you would need to add a project dependency on Log4j.  Maven would then take the dependency information and create a "signature" to search for, first in the local cache, and then in the external repositories.

Such a signature might look like

```
groupId:artifactId:version
```

or perhaps

```
groupId:artifactId:version:classifier
```

This identifies a maven "module" which will then be downloaded and configured into your system.  Once in place it **adds all of the classes within the module** to your configured project.

Comment: When you say "add a project dependency on Log4j", are you talking about opening the POM, clicking on the dependencies tab, and then searching for Log4j, using the Group ID, Artifact ID, etc?

Comment: The pom is a file, called pom.xml.  You are probably using a tool to write and rewrite the file automatically.  Open the file directly and you will see a "dependency" block in XML tags.  At least in the initial phases of learning maven, it is useful to peek at the XML to determine what is really set in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Maven principally saves time in downloading and organizing JAR files in your build.   By defining a "standard" project layout and a "standard" build order, Maven eliminates a lot of the guesswork in the "why isn't my project building" sweepstakes.   Also, you can use neat commands like "mvn dependency:tree" to print out a list of all the JARs your project depends on, recursively.

Warning note:  If you are using the M2E plugin and Eclipse, you may also run into problems with the plugin itself.  The 1.0 version (hosted at eclipse.org) was much less friendly than the previous 0.12 version (hosted at Sonatype).   You can get around this to some extent by downloading and installing the "standalone" version of Maven from apache (maven.apache.org) and running Maven from the command line.   This is actually much more stable than trying to run Maven inside Eclipse (in my personal experience) and may save you some pain as you try to learn about Maven.